# Symfony2 : Using different hosts and keep users logged in in all hosts. With JMSI18nRoutingBundle and FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using JMSI18nRoutingBundle and configured [scenario 3](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration).
So, my users are redirected to the host corresponding to their locale.

- foo.com
- foo.fr
- foo.nl
- foo.es
- foo.de

Everything works great except that I've session problem.

Session cookies are for one domain, so when the user is logged in in foo.com and switch to foo.fr, he is asked to log in again.
(I'm using FOSUSerBundle)

I'd like to keep the user logged in for all hosts.

I've seen solutions for subdomain but in my case it's multiple domain.

Does anyone could help me with this ?

Thank you,